# Understanding the Low Quality Posts Review queue

Tags: discussion

How did [this answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/5341) end up in the Low Quality Posts Review queue? It looks good as far as content and length is concerned.

<sub>I even clicked on the Edit link to see if there are any hidden/spam content but found nothing.</sub>

Comment: There was a mod flag on this post, not sure if that impacted or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked the flag history and it was flagged by a community member as very low quality answer... so the flag comes from the community and it reflects on the review queue.